# Pyinstaller fails with Python FBX

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fbx

I wrote a simple test script for Python FBX from Autodesk (http://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview). It reads an .FBX file and prints out some information on the file's contents.

It works fine when running the .py but when using Pyinstaller to turn it into an EXE, it fails with this error:

```
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
File ".....\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
  module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
ImportError: No module named fbxsip
```

I have no idea what fbxsip is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though pyinstaller is not able to resolve the dependencies on the Autodesk SDK.

fbxsip.pyd is part of the Autodesk SDK.

Most likely you will need to modify your spec to explicitly include fbxsip.pyd and fbx.pyd

Answer (score 0):

1) copy the FBX SDK to your Application directory

```
App:
   ...
   fbx.pyd
   fbxsip.pyd
   FbxCommon.py
```

2) then when you import fbx, force python to import fbxsip even you don't need it

```
from fbx import *
import fbxsip
```

maybe the first step is not necessary, but i didn't try it.